# Would edges with negative weights affect Prim's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

I was studying graphs and it got me wondering if edges with negative weights affected the outcome of Prim's Algorithm in finding a minimum spanning tree. So would the Prim's algorithm still find a suitable MST unaffected by negative weights on the edges of the graph?

Comment: I suggest that you try creating a small example of a tree with negative weights, and run Prim's algorithm by hand on that example.  Did that edge affect the outcome of the algorithm?  I think you should be able to answer your question on your own if you try a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a sufficiently-large constant to every edge of your graph, large enough to make all the edges positive, would the algorithm perform any different on the original graph than it would on this increased-weight version?